# splice odd/evens numbers in multidimensional array but result one or two odd/numbers show off

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, matrix, multidimensional-array

i am trying to splice the odd/evens numbers, look this, i tried to find odd numbers , but on the results array, evens numbers still there ,

```js
function find(index){
for(var i = 0 ; i < index.length;i++) {
  for(var j = 0 ; j < index[i].length ; j++) {
    if(index[i][j] % 2 === 1) { // trying to find odd numbers
      index[i].splice(j, 1)
    } 
  }
}
return index
}

var data = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
]

var another = [
  [2, 2, 7],
  [1, 3, 5, 6],
  [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]
]
console.log(find(data))
console.log(find(another))
```

is there any wrong with my codes ?? or i missed something? :)

Comment: Can you show what the expected output is meant to be.

Comment: Best not to use `splice`, especially while you're iterating over the array you're splicing. Use `.filter` instead

Comment: You can however splice in the loop if you iterate the array backwards....right to left

Comment: can you show me how @charlietfl

Comment: As in `for(var j = index[i].length-1; j >=0; j--) {...`

Comment: that is really work @charlietfl thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are mutating the array as you loop over it.

ie. on the second row of your second array, (`[1,3,5,6]`), lets think about what happens:

- i =1, j = 0
- the number (1) is odd, so you splice it, the array now looks like `[3,5,9]`
- i = 1, j = 1, the number is 5, is odd, so you remove it. You skipped over 3.
- i = 1, j=2, length of the row is 2, so the loop ends.

I've added a console log to your code that demonstrates this.

```js
function find(index){
for(var i = 0 ; i < index.length;i++) {
  for(var j = 0 ; j < index[i].length ; j++) {
    if (i ===1) console.log(`i = ${i}, j=${j}, index[i]  = ${index[i]}, index[i].length=${index[i].length}`); 
    if(index[i][j] % 2 === 1) { // trying to find odd numbers
      index[i].splice(j, 1)
    } 
  }
}
return index
}

var another = [
  [2, 2, 7],
  [1, 3, 5, 6],
  [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]
]
console.log(find(another))
```

So generally, as a rule, don't loop over arrays and mutate them.

Instead, I recommend using the [Array.prototype methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype#Methods) where you can, instead of loops.

A CertainPerformance suggests - you could use filter here instead.

```js
function find(array){
    //Assuming array is a 2d array. 
    return array.map(row => row.filter(v => v%2 ===0)); 

}

var data = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
]

var another = [
  [2, 2, 7],
  [1, 3, 5, 6],
  [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]
]
console.log(find(data))
console.log(find(another))
```

Note that this does return some empty arrays, which maybe you want to keep, or maybe you want to filter again to remove the empty arrays.

Note that, if you're not familiar with it - I'm using the [ES6 fat arrow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) syntax in my answer.

Comment: i do love to know just use loops :D